# FindAll in node with a mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm really newbie with these 2 techs mongo and nodejs.

I have a document in my Symfony project mapped into A mongo database.

```
    const collection = client.db(dbName).collection('MessageUser');
```

I would like to delete from mongo all the message from a conversation.

So I made this:

```
    socket.on('conv_reset',function (idConv) {
        io.to(room).emit('conv_reset_emit', "For conversation "+idConv+" getting all messages");
        var query = {idConversation : idConv };
        collection.find(query).toArray(function (err,result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            io.to(room).emit('conv_reset_emit', "Delete :" +result);
            collection.deleteOne()(result);
        })
    });
```

When I look into what is emitted; I have first something like FOr conversation 39 getting all messages.

So that means I receive properly the parameter.

Then I would like to do something similar to a findByIdConversation in php.

But when I look into the result I have; Delete undefined.

So I guess something isn't right...either the query part, either the find part....may be both. I don't really know.

Thanks for your help. I think this is a really basic problem...but I don't the right way into the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete multiple documents from MongoDB you can use [deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#db.collection.deleteMany) function like `db.collection.deleteMany()`. 
It will remove all documents that match the filter from a collection.

The syntax will be as below:

```
db.collection.deleteMany(
   <filter>,
   {
      writeConcern: <document>
   }
)
```

In your case, you should pass the same query which you are passing in find() function.

Try replacing `collection.deleteOne()(result);` with query as below:

```
collection.deleteMany(query).exec()
```

Comment: Looks like it makes the socket crash (so as my first version).

Comment: Actually it's my bad it's working if we keep the callback: lile `collection.deleteMany(query , (err , res) => {`